# Struct initialization problem in C

Tags: c, struct

I seem to be having a problem setting the values of an array inside a structure with a meaningless error spat out of the compiler:

> expected primary-expression before '{' token

I understand that a structure must "exist" to accept values, and it exists as a pointer to one. I would like you to explain to me what i am doing wrong and how to achieve my objective.

```
struct EventCheckData {
  unsigned long refresh_time;
  unsigned long last_execution_ms; //Can also serve to delay at startup
  byte signal_type;
};

struct ClockData {
    struct EventCheckData event_array[4];
    byte event_count;
    unsigned long last_absolute_time;
    UISignal *warning_signals;
}; 



 void ResetClock(UISignal *warning_signal, struct ClockData *clock_data, unsigned long absolute_time) { 
    if(SignalCheckValue(warning_signal, RESET_CLOCK, 1)) {
        extern volatile unsigned long timer0_overflow_count;
        timer0_overflow_count = 0;
        clock_data->last_absolute_time = absolute_time;
        clock_data->event_count = 3;
        (clock_data->event_array)[0] = { .refresh_time = 3000UL, .last_execution_ms = 0UL, .signal_type = WATER_PUMP_ON};
//      clock_data->event_array[1] = {10000UL, 0UL, EXPORT_LOG};
//      clock_data->event_array[2] = {100000UL, 0UL, EXTERNAL_CONNECTION};
        SignalSet(warning_signal, RESET_CLOCK, 0);
    }
}
```

Thank you
Paulo Neves

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(clock_data->event_array)[0] = { .refresh_time = 3000UL, .last_execution_ms = 0UL, .signal_type = WATER_PUMP_ON};` is not initialization. It is assignment.

And you cannot use initializer syntax in assignment.

With C99, you should be able to use a compound literal, like

```
(clock_data->event_array)[0] = (struct EventCheckData){ .refresh_time = 3000UL, .last_execution_ms = 0UL, .signal_type = WATER_PUMP_ON};
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you are assigning it looks like an initializer. You need assignment, try a compound literal:

```
clock_data->event_array[0] = (struct EventCheckData){ .refresh_time = 3000UL, ...};
```

Comment: Are you sure you can do that in C?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Why not ? It's been 12 years and the OP is already showing signs of c99 :-)

Comment: Then I never realised that this was a feature in C99!

Comment: wow such a subtility. I understand but i think i would have not spotted it

Answer (score 3):

Without any C99 stuff you can simply use:

```
void ResetClock(UISignal *warning_signal, struct ClockData *clock_data, unsigned long absolute_time) { 
if(SignalCheckValue(warning_signal, RESET_CLOCK, 1)) {
  extern volatile unsigned long timer0_overflow_count;
  timer0_overflow_count = 0;
  clock_data->last_absolute_time = absolute_time;
  clock_data->event_count = 3;
  {
    struct EventCheckData a[]={ {3000UL, 0UL, WATER_PUMP_ON},
                                {10000UL, 0UL, EXPORT_LOG},
                                {100000UL, 0UL, EXTERNAL_CONNECTION}};
    memcpy(clock_data->event_array,a,sizeof a);
  }
  SignalSet(warning_signal, RESET_CLOCK, 0);
}
```